# How to put Facebook and Twitter buttons next to each other?

Tags: html, css, facebook-like, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I've been trying to solve this for 5 hours now and nothing I do seems to work. I have a Facebook like button and a Twitter follow button and I want them to be side by side but the Twitter button keeps coming up on the line underneath. I'm using Twitter Boostrap. This is my haml code:

```
#social-media-container.container
%ul.social-media-buttons
    %span.span3.offset2
        %li.socialmedia
            %h3 Like us on Facebook
            .facebook-like-button
            %script{:src => "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"} 
            %fb:like{:layout => "button_count", :show_faces => "false", :width => "100"}
%ul.social-media-buttons
    %span.span3.offset6
        %li.socialmedia
            %h3 Follow us on Twitter
            %a.twitter-follow-button{"data-count" => "horizontal", :href => "https://twitter.com/..."}Follow ...
            %script{:src => "http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
```

And my CSS code:

```
.social-media-buttons{
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 5px 0 20px 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
```

}

```
ul.social-media-buttons li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
twitter-follow-button{
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Any idea how to fix this? I've tried several other ways as well with display: inline; to no avail.

Comment: @Anoel: Why do you have a span wrapping the list item in the `.social-media-buttons` list?

Comment: The span was there to try to offset them towards the center. They were there before I switched it to ul and I didn't think to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes with your HAML code. For starters you are creating an empty `div`. I am presuming that you want the div to work as a wrapper for the `.social-media-buttons` unordered list. In that case your HAML should look like this:

```
#social-media-container.container
    %ul.social-media-buttons
        %li.socialmedia
            %h3 Like us on Facebook
            .facebook-like-button
            %script{:src => "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"} 
            %fb:like{:layout => "button_count", :show_faces => "false", :width => "100"}
        %li.socialmedia
            %h3 Follow us on Twitter
            %a.twitter-follow-button{"data-count" => "horizontal", :href => "https://twitter.com/..."}Follow ...
            %script{:src => "http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
```

What this does is it creates the `div` as a wrapper for the **one** `social-media-buttons` unordered list. In your HAML code you had two unordered lists. One for the Facebook like and another one for the Twitter. I also removed the unwanted `span` that was wrapping the `li`. Having a `span` wrap a list item is invalid HTML. If you want to style the content inside the list items then I would suggest adding the styles for the headings, div or a tag inside the list items.

Try this code out and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to that and then added an .offset3 to the .social-media-buttons and it worked to center it.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the `span` wrapping your list items (it is supposed to wrap the list block) you're offsetting your twitter button out of the same line as the facebook button, so just remove that offset and both button should line up just fine.

Un-Haml'd Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mJ3BV/1/